# Joomla : Showing related articles from a specific category

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-module

I have articles under 'Projects', 'Services' and 'People' categories. I am displaying 'Related Articles' as a module on right side. It displays all related articles (based on tags) from all categories. I want to separate these related articles based on categories.

So, three modules (or one module with three categories) should appear in right side - 'Related Projects', 'Related Services' and 'Related People'. Possible?

I found one related question at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/module-to-show-all-articles-with-tag-and-in-a-category. However, it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module (RAXO Related Articles) can do exactly as you ask:
http://www.raxo.org/raxo-related-articles.html

Here you can flexibly manage from which categories you want to show Joomla related articles.

It can be current category - and the module automatically defines it and displays related items accordingly.
Or you can specify category or categories where the module should look for related articles.